# How to add checkbox for each dropdown list element in jsp

Tags: java, jquery, html, jsp, drop-down-menu

I wanted to  select several items from dropdown list by using checkboxes.

```
<div multiple size="2" id="-">
<select name="-" class="-" id="-" multiple>
    <option value="<s:property value="-"/>" selected="selected">                   
      <fmt:message  key="-" /></option>
    <s:iterator status="status" value="-">
        <option
            <s:iterator status="-" value="-"  id="-">                                           
                selected="selected"
            </s:iterator>
            value='<s:property value="-"/>'>
            <fmt:message key="-"></fmt:message>
        </option>
    </s:iterator>
</select>
```

Comment: What have you tried? There are different Javascript lib's which allow you to do that

Comment: San, I have Pasted my code, I used 'multiple' for selecting more than one item. I wanted checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Out of box, HTML doesn't support this functionality. You will have to make use of combination of JavaScript & HTML to achieve the desired effect. With the usage of `multiple` attribute you should get similar behavior, but if your usability demands to have list with checks, then you can try out following approach

- First create a hidden field whose value will be used to identify the user selection.
- Render a div with set of checkboxes and label (Use CSS to give desired effect)
- On click of checkbox, check the state of the checkbox and update the value appropriately in the hidden field created in step 1.

Note: You can find many libraries providing the similar behaviour. You can find it [here](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-multiselect-plugin/).

Comment: If this post has helped you, can you please accept it as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

http://dropdown-check-list.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/dropdownchecklist.html

This is good source to start with. As far as i know, you will have to use some JavaScripts. Plus, using library like jQuery will make it much easy to implement.

```
$("#s1").dropdownchecklist();
```

You just write a select html element, and render it using JS function like this.